# Django Models - Many to many persistent order

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm looking for a way to have a [Many-to-many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) relationship between objects while still persisting order. An example use case for this is a signup sheet. A user can sign up for many events, but I need to know who signed up first, second, third, etc...

Is there a straight forward way to doing this?

Comment: Add a timestamp field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two easy ways of doing such a thing:

1. Use a timestamp, as already suggested by **Moses Koledoye**.
2. Use any SEQUENCE number (or a SERIAL column).

For instance, let's assume these are your `users` and `events` tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    user_id INTEGER /* or SERIAL */ PRIMARY KEY,
    user_name text
) ;

CREATE TABLE events
(
    event_id INTEGER /* or SERIAL */ PRIMARY KEY,
    event_name text
) ;
```

You could define the many-to-many connection table in two different ways:

```
CREATE TABLE users_x_events
(
    user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users (user_id),
    event_id INTEGER REFERENCES events (event_id),
    created_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, event_id)
) ;

CREATE TABLE users_x_events_v2
(
    user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users (user_id),
    event_id INTEGER REFERENCES events (event_id),
    serial_id SERIAL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, event_id)
) ;
```

I do prefer to have a timestamp than a serial, because it gives a piece of information that is normally useful. You often want to know *when* things happened (and *who* made them).

If you want extra security, you can have an `ON BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger(s) to prevent any change to the `created_at` (or `serial_id`) column.

Comment: There is usually no reason to go with `timestamp` instead of `timestamptz`. They both are 8 bytes, while `timestamptz` is "smarter". (See for example this post by Momjian: https://momjian.us/main/blogs/pgblog/2017.html#June_19_2017)

Comment: @Nick: I've always found the name of the type to be absolutely misleading: `WITH TIME ZONE` should be called `WITH TIME ZONE TRANSLATION`, because no information about the time zone is stored. The time is just stored as UTC, and, when displayed (or converted to text), adjusted to the time zone of the client (and not at the time zone where the event took place). So, it should actually be called `UTC TIMESTAMP` or `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE TRANSLATION`. That might be one (semi-conscious) reason I try to avoid this type.

Comment: there is timezone of client, and also there is timezone of the initial value that was inserted. You can think about "timestamp with time zone" like about smarter data type which has information about both time zones. No matter how it's stored (it's hidden from the client), what is important is logic and capabilities.